# Sending variable length arrays over a network?

Tags: c++, networking

In the game I'm making, I nee to be able to send std::vectors of integer over a network.

A packet seems to be made up entirely of a string. Since enet, the network libray im using takes care of endian, my first idea on solving this is to send a messsage where the first byte is the message id, as usual, the next 4 bytes would be an integer indicating the length of the array, and all subsequent bytes would be  the ints in the array. On the client side I can then push these back into a vector.

Is this how it is usually done or am I missing something critical? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Either prefix with size or end with sentinel, that is how it is usually done.

Comment: Don't send the vector, send the array the vector manages.

Comment: Don't forget to convert to network byte order before putting on the wire and back again when taking off.

Comment: You could use Thrift to provide you with a handy IPC framework with a very natural C++ feel.

Comment: @Lou doesn't enet do this for me?

Comment: Try reading about serialization, this is how the process of transmitting runtime data over a binary interface is called.

Comment: generally it is a good idea to put the length of what is coming next first, rather than working with sentinels, as you can then properly allocate on the receiver side.

Comment: @immortal: not at all, serialization is about saving data (and being able to restore them) while messenging is about exchanging data (not necessarily over the wire). The difference comes from the fact that serialization usually imply a 1-1 mapping between the objects and the format while messenging imply a more or less neutral interface format.

Comment: @Milo eNet will do this for it's data (packet headers and what not) but won't do it for the body of your message. The comms stack doesn't know what you are sending, it just knows you are sending a stream of bytes. If you send ints from a big endian to a little endian computer, failure to convert ints to network byte order before sending and converting back when receiving will result in the integer values changing when being interpreted by your code. ntohl and htonl will do all this for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there are two approaches to solving this problem which can be combined. One is to put the length of the array before the actual array. The other involves including some framing to mark the end (or beginning) of your message. There are advantages and disadvantages to each.

Putting the length before the array is simplest. However, if there should ever be a bug where the length does not match the number of integers, there is no way to detect this or recover from it.

Using a framing byte(s) to mark the end of the message has the advantage of more robustness and the ability to recover from an improperly formatted message at the cost of complexity. The complexity comes in the fact that if your framing bytes  appear in your array of integers, you must escape the bytes (i.e. prepend and escape character). Also, your code to read messages from the network becomes a little more complicated.

Of course, this all assumes that you are dealing stream and not a datagram. If your messages are clearly packetized already, then the length should be enough.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how sending a sentinel value (versus prefixing a length) makes it easier to recover from an error.  Can you elaborate on that?  Two of the basic errors are 1) Sender sends too little data and receiver waits until some kind of timeout.  2) Sender sends too much data and receiver stops reading too soon because it thinks it has it all.  Both situations can happen with both methods.  Why can you recover in one situation but not the other?

Comment: If you have the sentinel, your receiver looks for the sentinel as part of reading data off a socket. If the sentinel appears in the stream and the message is not complete, then the message can be discarded. If you read the expected number of bytes and then don't see the sentinel, you know that you can discard the rest of the bytes until the sentinel arrives. In either case, you know the beginning of the next message. I should've said that when using the sentinel, you should still include length information as part of the message. Sentinel just allows error recovery.

Comment: That seems like a good argument.  However, it sounds like the goal is to recover from a client doing the wrong thing.  If that's the case, the client may never send the sentinel value either.  Then the server just waits anyway.  Or the client might send random data after the sentinel.  I don't really see a difference.

Comment: There is no way to recover from everything. However, detecting there is a problem can allow you to notify the client that there is a problem in his data stream or at least log the error at the server. This is method I've used in the past. It is not always necessary and maybe overkill.

Comment: That is true.  And it certainly doesn't hurt; there is no real extra cost to speak of.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to send variable length data on a stream: by prefixing the data with the length, or by suffixing it with a delimiter.

A suffix can have a theoretically infinite size, but it means the delimiter must not appear in the data. This approach can be used for strings, with a NUL (`'\0'`) character as the delimiter.

When dealing with binary data, then you don't have any choice but to prefix the length. The size of the data will be limited to the the size of the prefix, which is rarely a problem with a 4 byte prefix (because otherwise it means you're sending more than 4 gigabytes of data).

So, it all depends on the data being sent.

Comment: A lot of wire protocols (FastCGI and Websockets come to mind) allow a variable length prefix.  Define a special "escape" byte to avoid paying extra overhead for the prefix on small packets.

Answer (score 0):

Appending that header information to your packet is a good approach to take.  Another option you can do on the receive side, if the data is stored in some `unsigned char*` buffer of memory, is create a structure like so:

```
typedef struct network_packet
{
    char id;
    int message_size;
    int data[];
} __attribute__((packed)) network_packet;
```

You can then simply "overlay" this structure on-top of your received buffer like so:

```
unsigned char* buffer;
//...fill the buffer and make sure it's the right size -- endian is taken care of
//via library

network_packet* packet_ptr = (network_packet*)buffer;

//access the 10th integer in the packet if the packet_ptr->message_size
//is long enough
if (packet_ptr->message_size >= 10)
    int tenth_int = packet_ptr->data[9];
```

This will avoid you having to go through the expense of copying all the data back, which already exists in a buffer, back into another `std::vector` on the receive side.